# VS Code On Apple M1 Pro Is Painfully Slow When Searching Files With Command + P

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code 1.70.2 and have been using the SSH Remote extension to connect to a local Linux server's codebase. For years the `Command + P` file-search functionality was lighting-quick and was a very handy tool in large codebases, but in the last 2 weeks, the functionality has ground to a halt, taking upwards of 9 seconds to perform a file-search.

I have disabled all extensions (except `Remote - SSH`, of course), I have tried multiple versions of VS Code (including the latest "nightly" version), I have restarted the remote server, I have measured the speed between the two hosts, which is roughly 700MB/s, I have deleted the `.vscode-server` directory on the remote server, and I have created a brand-new project in the same folder.

I have also added very-liberal globs to the "Search - Exclude" settings to see if packages/vendor libraries were the issue, and still no performance improvement. Only when I try to manipulate a *local* codebase does the file-search functionality work at an acceptable speed.

I have run out of things to try. Am I doomed to deal with excessively-slow file searching, or is there another place to try and debug this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: @Antoni I took the issue to GitHub, and after a few weeks, they randomly released an update and it "fixed itself." I wish I had a better solution, but updating (I use VS Code Insider) certainly fixed it for me a couple weeks ago.

Comment: If all else fails one option is to just use a local copy of the codebase and then use a local file watcher + rsync to sync any changes back to the server in real-time as you modify them.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me try it out. Add this to User settings.
Ctrl+Shift+P(Windows) / Cmd+Shift+P(OSX)
Open user settings in JSON

```
"search.exclude": {
  "**/.*": true,
  "**/.gitignore": true
},
"search.followSymlinks": false,
    "files.exclude": {
 "**/.*": true
    
}
```