# vscode command + p search is very slow?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

After I enter command + p and the file name to search, the search function is always loading and can not find the file, does anyone konw what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74541168/20574850 [ Check this out, try excluding additional un-necessary modules/folders]